# Issues with Android Soft Keyboard and panAdjust

Tags: java, android, layout, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to achieve similar effect to the one found in Todoits application where you can click on FAB and it shows a floating popup for adding new task. 
This is how it looks:

[image]

The closest to it I managed to achieve is this:

[image]

It is nearly there, but I want the popup to be about 10dp above the keyboard and scroll the recycle viewer to the last item but I can't get it there :/ Currently, the popup is centred.

I have tried before adding the popup to the bottom of the screen and setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but this was moving my bottom navigation above the keyboard too. Setting windowsSoftInputMode to panAdjust was cutting away the toolbar and few items from the list.

Have you got any suggestions about how to achieve similar effect to the one in Todoist? Maybe with a DialogFragment?

Below is my current code (navigation bar implementation is still not completed): 
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private WorkoutsListFragment workoutsListFragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    this.workoutsListFragment = new WorkoutsListFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.main_layout, workoutsListFragment)
        .commit();
  }
}
```

WorkoutListFragment:

```
public class WorkoutsListFragment extends Fragment
    implements View.OnClickListener, WorkoutListViewHolderInterface {

  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  private WorkoutListRecycleViewAdapter recycleViewAdapter;
  private AddBoxView addBoxView;
  private FloatingActionButton actionButton;
  private InputMethodManager imm;
  private WorkoutViewModel workoutViewModel;
  private boolean addBoxStatus;

  public WorkoutsListFragment() {}

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.addBoxStatus = false;
   //Irrelevant code removed (Dagger 2 DI)

    this.workoutViewModel =
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, workoutViewModelFactory).get(WorkoutViewModel.class);

    workoutViewModel.init(7);
    workoutViewModel.getWorkout().observe(this, w -> this.updateWorkoutsList(w, false));

    this.imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(
      @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_workouts_list, container, false);
    this.recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.workoutsList);
    //        this.recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    this.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayoutManager);

    this.recycleViewAdapter = new WorkoutListRecycleViewAdapter(this);
    this.recyclerView.setAdapter(recycleViewAdapter);

    this.actionButton = view.findViewById(R.id.floating_action_add_workout);
    this.actionButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    this.addBoxView = new AddBoxView(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams addBoxLayoutParams =
        new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.CENTER);

    this.addBoxView.setLayoutParams(addBoxLayoutParams);
    this.addBoxView.getButton().setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.floating_action_add_workout:
        this.addBoxView((FrameLayout) v.getParent(), v);
        break;
      case R.id.overlay_layout:
        removeAddBoxView((FrameLayout) v);
        break;
      case R.id.button:
        this.addNewWorkout(this.addBoxView.getInputText());
        break;
    }
  }


//Irrelevant code removed.... 

  private void addBoxView(FrameLayout viewGroup, View v) {
    this.addBoxStatus = true;
    viewGroup.setClickable(true);
    viewGroup.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview_shadow_start_color, null));
    viewGroup.removeView(v);
    viewGroup.addView(this.addBoxView);
    this.addBoxView.requestInputFocus();
    this.imm.showSoftInput(this.addBoxView.getInput(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
  }

  private void removeAddBoxView(FrameLayout viewGroup) {
    viewGroup.setClickable(false);
    this.imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.addBoxView.getInput().getWindowToken(), 0);
    viewGroup.removeView(this.addBoxView);
    viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.cardview_shadow_end_color, null));
    viewGroup.addView(this.actionButton);
    this.addBoxStatus = false;
  }
}
```

Fragment_workouts_list layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e1e1e1"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity.Fragments.Workouts.WorkoutsListFragment"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/workoutsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/add_box_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlay_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:outlineProvider="bounds">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_add_workout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/my_toolbar">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use adjustResize and hide the bottom navigation while showing the keyboard

Comment: I've tried that. It gets the job done but it's very glittery and FAB is first popping above the keyboard and then back in its place once the keyboard is gone. Do you think adding animation could help by delaying the time when FAB actually shows up?

Comment: Yes, I have floating buttons bound to the bottom of my views, using animate layout changes = true on the parent layout. It looks great.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try it first thing tomorrow morning :)